# Re-Centering JQuery Tooltips when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, tooltip

I have written a function that positions a tooltip just above a textbox.

The function takes two arguments:

- **textBoxId** - The ID of the textbox above which the tooltip will appear.

  - **Example**: *"#textBoxA"*
- **toolTipId** - The ID of the tooltip which will appear above the textbox.

  - **Example**: *"#toolTipA"*

```
    function positionTooltip(textBoxId, toolTipId){

        var hoverElementOffsetLeft = $(textBoxId).offset().left;
        var hoverElementOffsetWidth = $(textBoxId)[0].offsetWidth;

        var toolTipElementOffsetLeft = $(toolTipId).offset().left;
        var toolTipElementOffsetWidth = $(toolTipId)[0].offsetWidth;

        // calcluate the x coordinate of the center of the hover element.
        var hoverElementCenterX =
            hoverElementOffsetLeft + (hoverElementOffsetWidth / 2);

        // calculate half the width of the toolTipElement
        var toolTipElementHalfWidth = toolTipElementOffsetWidth / 2;
        var toolTipElementLeft = hoverElementCenterX - toolTipElementHalfWidth;

        $(toolTipId)[0].style.left = toolTipElementLeft + "px";


        var toolTipElementHeight = $(toolTipId)[0].offsetHeight;
        var hoverElementOffsetTop = $(textBoxId).offset().top;
        var toolTipYCoord = hoverElementOffsetTop - toolTipElementHeight;
        toolTipYCoord = toolTipYCoord - 10;
        $(toolTipId)[0].style.top = toolTipYCoord + "px";

        $(toolTipId).hide();
$(textBoxId).hover(
 function(){ $(toolTipId + ':hidden').fadeIn(); },
 function(){ $(toolTipId + ':visible').fadeOut(); }
);

$(textBoxId).focus (
 function(){ $(toolTipId + ':hidden').fadeIn(); }
);

$(textBoxId).blur (
 function(){ $(toolTipId+ ':visible').fadeOut(); }
);


    }
```

---

The function works fine upon initial page load:
[image]

---

However, after the user resizes the window the tooltips move to locations that no longer display above their associated textbox.

[image]

---

I've tried writing some code to fix the problem by calling the positionTooltip() function when the window is resized but for some reason the tooltips do not get repositioned as they did when the page loaded:

```
            var _resize_timer = null;

            $(window).resize(function() {

             if (_resize_timer) {clearTimeout(_resize_timer);}


            _resize_timer = setTimeout(function(){

                 positionTooltip('#textBoxA', ('#toolTipA'));

            }, 1000);
        });
```

I'm really at a loss here as to why it doesn't reposition the tooltip correctly as it did when the page was initially loaded after a resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for calculating the position of the tooltip only fires initially when you call positionTooltip.  You want to call it to recalculate position before the fadeIn call.

Comment: @CptSkippy Kudos!  Thanks for the help Chief! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you use a setTimeout() to launch your function. Try

```
$(function(){
// all your code onDocumentReady
...
...
            $(window).resize(function() {
                 positionTooltip('#textBoxA', ('#toolTipA'));
        });


});
```

Comment: I did that because what you have written above didn't work first. 

I figured that if the issue was that the offset position of the textbox hadn't been set yet when the resize method was called; the timeout would give the offset of the textbox time to be set.

Comment: can you post a sample on http://jsbin.com/  with some representative html markup to play with?

Answer (score 0):

That worked like a charm for me, the only drawback is that sometimes it dosen't get the proper X,Y position, apparently not it's compensating with object's padding/margin values, i did a dirty fix by adding those values manually before they are set like:

```
  toolTipElementLeft = toolTipElementLeft + 40;
  $(toolTipId)[0].style.left = toolTipElementLeft + "px";
```

and

```
  toolTipYCoord = toolTipYCoord + 25;
  $(toolTipId)[0].style.top = toolTipYCoord + "px";
```